# Power BI Desktop cannot connect to azure SQL

Tags: azure, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I am trying to establish a connection to an azure SQL database from Power BI Desktop. I enter the server and database names as per the following screenshot:

[image]

I keep getting the following error:

[image]

Additionally, I am able to connect form the same Power BI Desktop to another azure SQL database on the same azure SQL server. 
I checked for typos, for the azure firewall settings including my client IP and for "Allow access to Azure services" set to ON. The fact that one of the databases in the same server is connecting correctly make me consider if there is a limitation on Power BI desktop to one only database per azure SQL server.

Comment: Do you have "allow access to azure services" enabled on the firewall?

Comment: Yes It is enabled. I will add as an edit.

Comment: Rather than saying how you solved the problem in the question, it'd be better to post it as an actual answer. That way it's more obvious that a solution to the problem exists (people with the same problem may not read your entire question if they see it's unanswered).

Comment: I will move it to an answer thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was finally able to establish the connection with the azure SQL server by replacing Server field above with: tcp:myServerName.database.windows.net,1433 and leaving the Database field empty. 
This allowed me to connect to both databases in the server and didn't request credentials.
Somehow power pi desktop was not letting me create a new connection to another database under the same server. This has not been made clear in Power BI desktop documentation and examples.